# Move Fragment from view pager to another container

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

**Update**
Ok, I figured out what is the prolem. I try to find fragment by tag, but when I add it to the adapter, I can't set tag for the fragment.
But I don't know how can I add.

I use a landscape and a portrait in my app. Landscape layout contains two constrait layout, portrait layout contains a view page with a Fragment state pager. I have a Fragment with recycler view and another Fragment with a pie chart. When I rotate the phone from land to portrait I get an Exception, Fragment container has different ID, so I remove the Fragment from Fragment manager before I add it again. It solves the exception, but in this case I can't retain recycle view's state. 
How can I

Comment: by state means, scroll position? or you don't want to load all data of recycler?

Comment: did u tried what i mentioned in my answer? setRetainInstance?

Comment: I tried, but in this case, I get this exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hu.astron.rectruiting/hu.astron.rectruiting.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0b005a (hu.astron.rectruiting:id/pager) for fragment PersonsFragment{f9530d7 #0 id=0x7f0b005a}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out the what was the problem.
Before I add the fragments to the pager, I have to set a tag by add(fragment, tag).
It was the mistake, I didn't set tag for the fragments, so when I tried to find the fragment by tag, it was null, and I allways cretaed a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you want to stop your app from recreating when orientation changes. Add this line `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to your activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. This line stops app being recreated on orientation change it just changes orientation nothing else.

> Example

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: without recreating, how can he use different layouts for landscape and portrait?

Comment: Thanks, my problem isn't exaclty retain the fragment state.
My problem, I can't add my fragment to a container, after I added it to a FragmentStatePagerAdapter without call fragmentManager.remove().
However you can handle orientation change by override the 
onConfigurationChanged() method

Comment: @Farhan, yeah my bad, didn't consider that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly, but this function says, it will retain the fragment state. You might want to try this:

```
setRetainInstance
```

From [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean))

It will not destroy and recreate the Fragment only.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem not exactly with retain the fragment state, I can't add it to a container after I added it to a pager.

Comment: yeah same fragment can not be put into two views. AFAIK